# Is there a way to detect which console is active in an ActiveMQ Artemis master/slave?

Tags: activemq-artemis

We want to put a load-balancer (F5) pointing to web console of the ActiveMQ Artemis instance which is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActiveMQServerControl` MBean has a method called `isActive()` which returns `true` if the broker is active and `false` if it is not. That should allow you to point the load-balancer at the proper web console.

The [management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html) is exposed via JMX, management messages, HTTP (via Jolokia), etc. Here's an example using `curl`:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://localhost" -u myUser:myPass http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"/Active
```

This will return a JSON response, e.g.:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"",
    "attribute": "Active",
    "type": "read"
  },
  "value": true,
  "timestamp": 1663085210,
  "status": 200
}
```